# VSCode + vueJs no guarda los cambios

Tags: vue.js

Estoy trabajando con VisualStudioCode en donde uso Vuejs y Laravel....el error es el siguiente:

Si hago un cambio en una view de Laravel los cambios se ven instantaneamente en mi proyecto, **pero** si lo hago en VueJs (sea una vista, un componente lo que sea) no se ve...

La unica solucion es compilar con *npm run dev* pero esto no deberia ser la solucion ya que los cambios con laravel si se ven inmediatamente.

Alguna idea???

Comment: Debes darte una vuelta por acá: https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html para comprender el por que es necesario compilar un *SFC*

Answer (score 0):

Hola ese error se da cuando en tu componente no esta bien escrito, respeta el nombre del proyecto en "router/index.js" y el error se soluciona.!

Saludos de Costa Rica

Answer (score -1):

En mi caso se solucionó pasando el proyecto al sistema de archivos de Ubuntu, fuera del sistema de windows (`/mnt/C/user`). Como mágia ahí si funciona además de compilar mucho más rápido.